# What does ! at the end of a sentence in JS mean?

Tags: javascript

```
const response = await fetch(cameraPhoto.webPath!);
```

Taken from Ionic docs, https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/your-first-app/3-saving-photos

Comment: It mostly means that it's not JavaScript. The postfix `!` is used by TypeScript, for example.

Comment: that's not JS syntax, the author seems to have forgotten that they weren't writing typescript.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The examples on the linked page certainly were *meant* to be typescript even :-)